# Identify and tag music from iTunes library under OS X

Tags: itunes, software

I'm looking for a tool, preferably free, that would help me identify and correctly tag my itunes music collection.

Answer (score 4):

You have many choices, you can download one of these software and correct all of your ID3 Tags:

1. [TuneUP](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/index.php?gclid=CLOG9O6ugKQCFVMB4wodwXfkHA)
2. [Musicbrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Picard_Tagger)
3. [Jaikoz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaikoz)