# Mac music tagging software

Tags: mac, music

Since the switch from Windows to Mac, I've been looking for a good music tagging application for Mac OS X.

I've tried apps such as Tagalicious, TriTag and a few other apps, but none have made me happy so far. Basically I'm looking for something similar to Mp3Tag (which is Windows only).

Just asking before I consider starting an open source project and do this on my own.

Comment: what type of tagging you want? to correct Mp3 ID3 tag?

Comment: Yes. But it would be awesome to be able to edit tags for any other format too (e.g. FLAC).

Comment: so ckeck this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/identify-and-tag-music-from-itunes-library-under-os-x/10525#10525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- MediaRage: http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/MediaRage.html
- TuneUp: http://www.tuneupmedia.com/index.php
- Pollux: http://polluxapp.com/

You may also want to take a look at http://osx.iusethis.com/search?order=users&q=id3

Answer (score 1):

I've mostly used [TriTag](http://www.feedface.com/projects/tritag.html) or temporary AppleScripts like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in selection
        --set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
        --set ti to text items of n
        --set track number of t to item 1 of ti
        --set artist of t to item 2 of ti
        --set album of t to item 3 of ti
        --set name of t to item 4 of ti
        --set name of t to (get track number of t)
        --set name of t to my titlecase(get name of t)
    end repeat
end tell

on titlecase(x)
    do shell script "ruby -Ku -rubygems -e 'require \"titlecase\"; print STDIN.read.chomp.titlecase' <<< " & quoted form of x without altering line endings
end titlecase

on replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end replace

on split(input, x)
    if input does not contain x then return {input}
    set text item delimiters to x
    text items of input
end split
```

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps it is not much more convenient than using a dedicate application?